# Shardingsphere and Flyway integration startup error: Schema 'xxxx' doesn't exist

Tags: java, spring, flyway, sharding

I want to use Flyway to manage the database version, and I want to use the data source of shardingjdbc, but I encounter various problems when I start. How can I fix this problem?

#### Dependencies

shardingsphere-jdbc-core-spring-boot-starter:5.1.1
flyway-core:8.5.13
flyway-mysql:8.5.13
mysql-connector-j:8.0.33
jdk8

#### application.yaml

```yaml
spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude: com.alibaba.druid.spring.boot.autoconfigure.DruidDataSourceAutoConfigure
  shardingsphere:
    enabled: true
    datasource:
      schema:
        name: store
      names: store
      store:
        driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
        type: com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource
        username: root
        password: root
        url: jdbc:mysql://pigx-mysql:3306/store?characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=Asia/Shanghai
    props:
      sql-show: true
    rules:
      sharding:
        sharding-algorithms:
          table-inline:
            props:
              algorithm-expression: store_$->{tenant_id}
            type: INLINE
        tables:
          version:
            actual-data-nodes: store.t_version
            table-strategy:
              none:
          store:
            actual-data-nodes: store.store_1716476137853374465, store.store_1717116448820633602
            table-strategy:
              standard:
                sharding-algorithm-name: table-inline
                sharding-column: tenant_id
  ## flyway ---------------------------------
  flyway:
    enabled: true
    baseline-on-migrate: true
    clean-disabled: false
    out-of-order: true
```

The following exception is displayed when the startup is displayed:

[image]

```java
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed;
nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: Unable to check whether schema `store` exists

Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: Unable to check whether schema `store` exists

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'store.schemata' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:121) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:916) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
```

##### SQL execution logs

[image]

```sql
Logic SQL: SELECT COUNT(1) FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name=? LIMIT 1
Actual SQL: store ::: SELECT COUNT(1) FROM schemata WHERE schema_name=? LIMIT 1 ::: [store]
```

shardingjdbc routes SQL statements to the `store` database.
So I added the information_schema to the data source, and configured it as follows:

```yaml
   datasource:
      names: store, information_schema
      ....
      information_schema:
        driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
        type: com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource
        username: root
        password: root
        url: jdbc:mysql://pigx-mysql:3306/information_schema
      ...
    rules:
      ...
      sharding:
        tables:
            schemata:
              actual-data-nodes: information_schema.schemata
              table-strategy:
                none:
            tables:
              actual-data-nodes: information_schema.tables
              table-strategy:
                none:
     ...
```

The following is the startup execution log:

```java
Sql log:
Logic SQL:    SELECT COUNT(1) FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name=? LIMIT 1
Actual SQL:  information_schema ::: SELECT COUNT(1) FROM schemata WHERE schema_name=? LIMIT 1 ::: [store]

Exception information:

2023-10-30 22:36:40.986  WARN 23832 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.apache.shardingsphere.infra.exception.SchemaNotExistedException: Schema 'store' doesn't exist.
....

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.apache.shardingsphere.infra.exception.SchemaNotExistedException: Schema 'store' doesn't exist.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
....

Caused by: org.apache.shardingsphere.infra.exception.SchemaNotExistedException: Schema 'store' doesn't exist.
    at org.apache.shardingsphere.infra.binder.statement.dml.SelectStatementContext.getSchema(SelectStatementContext.java:138) ~[shardingsphere-infra-binder-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.apache.shardingsphere.infra.binder.statement.dml.SelectStatementContext.<init>(SelectStatementContext.java:111) ~[shardingsphere-infra-binder-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.apache.shardingsphere.infra.binder.SQLStatementContextFactory.getDMLStatementContext(SQLStatementContextFactory.java:146) ~[shardingsphere-infra-binder-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.apache.shardingsphere.infra.binder.SQLStatementContextFactory.newInstance(SQLStatementContextFactory.java:129) ~[shardingsphere-infra-binder-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.apache.shardingsphere.infra.binder.SQLStatementContextFactory.newInstance(SQLStatementContextFactory.java:114) ~[shardingsphere-infra-binder-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.apache.shardingsphere.driver.jdbc.core.statement.ShardingSpherePreparedStatement.<init>(ShardingSpherePreparedStatement.java:181) ~[shardingsphere-jdbc-core-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.apache.shardingsphere.driver.jdbc.core.statement.ShardingSpherePreparedStatement.<init>(ShardingSpherePreparedStatement.java:149) ~[shardingsphere-jdbc-core-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.apache.shardingsphere.driver.jdbc.core.connection.ShardingSphereConnection.prepareStatement(ShardingSphereConnection.java:80) ~[shardingsphere-jdbc-core-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcTemplate.prepareStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:300) ~[flyway-core-8.5.13.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:339) ~[flyway-core-8.5.13.jar:na]
....
```

shardingjdbc can't find the schema for the store, the break point is only the schema of the logic_db, please teach how to solve this problem

The Git project repository: https://github.com/8baba/flyway-shardingjdbc-test

How will I properly use Flyway to manage the database?

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77390141/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.